# How to use Glide Library Transformation properly?

Tags: android, transformation, android-glide

So I have any Image in an `imageView` loaded from my phone's gallery and I want to apply any Glide transformation

The code should be like this

```
Glide.with(context)
    .load(myimage)
    .bitmapTransform(new CropCircleTransformation(context))
    .into(myimage);
```

My problem is to know what to put into `context` so the transformation takes place when a Button is pressed.
I tried `Glide.with(this)` but it will give an error about `onClickListener` from the button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is `Activity` use

```
Glide.with(ActivityName.this).load(myimage)
     .bitmapTransform(new CropCircleTransformation(ActivityName.this)) .into(myimage);
```

With `Fragment` use

```
Glide.with(getActivity()).load(myimage)
     .bitmapTransform(new CropCircleTransformation(getActivity())) .into(myimage);
```

Comment: it does work but NOT when the button is pressed. I'm supposed to load my uri from "resultData.getData()" Intent into myimage, and not myimage into itself. Problem now is, how to acces that uri, which results from opening an image in the gallery, as declaring it outside the  public void onActivityResult won't recognize what "uri" is.

Answer (score 0):

In the onClick listener 'this' referes to the listener itself. Use YourActivityName.this